# Syntax Error, cannot parse from lucene StandardQueryparser when using fq(filtered query)

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, query-parser

I am trying to pass a java String to Apache StandardQueryparser to get the Querynode.

Input - `"fq=section:1"`

All I need is section:1 in FILTER clause in QueryNode. This looks pretty straightforward but it throws

`INVALID_SYNTAX_CANNOT_PARSE: Syntax Error, cannot parse fq=section:1:`

Comment: Are you trying to send `fq=section:1` as the _input_ to a query parser directly in Lucene? `fq` is Solr syntax, it's not directly related to Lucene. Add your actual code and what you're trying to do - if you just want to add an extra condition for `section:1`, you can add ` AND section:1` to your query, To replicate the `fq` behavior  to not affect score, use a `ConstantScoreQuery`.

Comment: I have a condition like ```(name: abc OR name: xyz) AND id:(1 2 3 )```. I pass this to StandardQueryParser and it parses to 2 bool queries. Bool query 1 is a "should" clause for the OR condition above. The second bool query also gets translated to a "should" clause for id part of it. But what I want to do is "filter" for id query not "should" as "filter" performs better than "should"

Comment: You can accept the answer or tell us what is missing for you to go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [a ConstantScoreQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreQuery.html). It won't affect it score, and [is the same was as the `fq` parameter is implemented in Solr](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/fbd05167f455e3ce2b2ead50336e2b9c2521cd6c/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/query/FilterQuery.java#L87):

```
  public Weight createWeight(IndexSearcher searcher, ScoreMode scoreMode, float boost) throws IOException {
    // SolrRequestInfo reqInfo = SolrRequestInfo.getRequestInfo();

    if (!(searcher instanceof SolrIndexSearcher)) {
      // delete-by-query won't have SolrIndexSearcher
      return new BoostQuery(new ConstantScoreQuery(q), 0).createWeight(searcher, scoreMode, 1f);
    }

    SolrIndexSearcher solrSearcher = (SolrIndexSearcher)searcher;
    DocSet docs = solrSearcher.getDocSet(q);
    // reqInfo.addCloseHook(docs);  // needed for off-heap refcounting

    return new BoostQuery(new SolrConstantScoreQuery(docs.getTopFilter()), 0).createWeight(searcher, scoreMode, 1f);
  }
```